# Disabling list item creation

Tags: list

SP 2007: I have a "master" list and a "slave" list.  Workflow attached to the "master" list creates items in the "slave" list based on data in the "master" list item.  Can I disable manual item creation in the "slave" list (or, alternately, create a "null" content type and set that as the default for the "slave" list) so that users cannot create an item directly in the "slave" list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could set permissions on the slave list to prevent users adding items. Then, your workflow code (is it a Visual Studio workflow or SPD?) could elevate privileges in order to be able to create the slave list items.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon one way to do this would be to use a custom NewForm.aspx page for the slave list, and hide the DataFormWebPart on that page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the control over the list definition, then setting the **SecurityBits** for you slave bits to **14** can prevent your users to modify that list..

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with Paul Lucas's approach, another idea might be an EventHandler - on ItemAdding, you could reject cancel the event - and prevent the item being created.

But permissions is probably the way to go.